# Савва - Саввич, Саввична, Никита - Никитич, Никитична, а что за суффикс у женских отчеств от Кузьмы и Ильи?

Tags: ономастика, антропонимика

Ильинична, Кузьминична, Лукинична, Фоминична, - что это за добавочное -ини-?

Откуда взялось, как повелось, есть ли прецеденты, кроме четырёх названных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://rusgram.narod.ru/380-432.html
  Да, наверно, оттуда, откуда и все остальные суффиксы отчеств - так сложилось.

морф -иничн(а)присутствует в образованиях, мотивированных отчествами с морфом -ич акцентного типа В(ударение на конец слова) от имен II скл. акц. типа А(Лука, Фома):

Илья- Ильич - Ильинична,Лука-Лукич - Лукинична, Кузьма-Кузьмич - Кузьминична, Фома-Фомич-Фоминична.

А так как других имён на ударное -а я что-то в современности не наблюдаю, видимо, их и нет, остались в древности.

Comment: Да, точно, Савва и Никита не на последний слог ударяются, поэтому и не так отчества получаются. Я бы выделил в Вашем ответе об ударении, чтобы заметнее было.

Answer (score 1):

Дети Кузьмы — Кузьмины. Дочернее «Кузьмин-**ичн**-а» включает в себя словообразовательный суффикс для именования лиц женского пола по отчеству. И далее, по этой же причине, — отчества у Ильиных, Фоминых, Лукиных барышень.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашла похожее на ответ, но, к сожалению, без необходимых мне разъяснений...

Эти отчества названы реликтовыми (явление под названием "мёртвые аффиксы"?), и бряцает оружием абсолютно невиданный-неслышанный доселе суффикс - йотовый...

Пример употребления (ниже) меня не вдохновил:

> ...Данное название справедливо связывают со святилищем Велеса, которое
>   естественно ожидать в ближайшей округе средневековой Ладоги - древней
>   столицы Северной Руси. Лингвистически форма Велеша - это
>   прилагательное, закономерно образованное с помощью «йотового» суффикса
>   принадлежности от основы Белее- (Велес-j- > Велеш-, буквально
>   «Велесово (место)»).
>
> «Йотовый» суффикс принадлежности, потерявший употребительность после
>   XII века, являлся весьма характерным для названий, производных от имен
>   людей. В «йотовой» деривации применительно к теониму читаются не
>   только глубокая архаичность рассматриваемых топонимов, но и древний
>   анимизм (индивидуальная принадлежность живому божеству)...

(Я задам о нём вопрос.)

И вот объяснения касательно отчеств, про ту же йотовую деривацию, только не закавыченную, - убей бог, это нам не задавали, это мы не проходили...

> В ранних отчествах был задействован йотовый суффикс (Вячеславъ сын
>   Ярославль (1057), посадник Костянтин сын Добрынь (1018), Иванко
>   Вячеславль (1127), впоследствии в отчествах не употреблявшийся.
>
> В настоящее время в качестве реликтов сохраняются формы некоторых
>   женских отчеств на -инична при мужских на -ич: Ильич – Ильинична,
>   Кузьмич – Кузьминична, Фомич – Фоминична, Лукич – Лукинична. В прошлом
>   отчества с суффиксом -инич могли быть у мужчин: пан Ильинич, наместник
>   смоленский (1498), Рагуилъ Прокопьиничь, новгородец (1200), Иванко
>   Захарьиничь (1171), Юрьи Олексиничь (1216).

Источники допзагадок:

[номер раз](https://vk.com/wall-92771058_49);

[номер два](http://www.krugosvet.ru/enc/gumanitarnye_nauki/lingvistika/ANTROPONIMIKA.html?page=0,9).

Comment: Спасибо за изыски. Про йотовый суффикс в курсе, но Вы ж про  -иничн  спрашивали. А вот что это остаток мужского отчества - не знала, спасибо. Знаю только, что потом суффикс -ич себе присвоили знатные люди. Простые так и остались сынами Ивана, а знатные и уважаемые  - Ивановичи. Но про то тоже вопроса не было. Надо было шире ставить.

Comment: Я ж не знала ж ничего ж - я выгуглила ж! И, несмотря на все мною же собранные примеры, продолжаю в упор не видеть йотового суффикса. Не понимаю: он слышится, но не видится? Так я разные транскрипции открывала - нэма ничого.

Comment: Ну как же не видите, -j-притяжательный суффикс к имени Ярославъ. Ярославъ  + j ;   в + j =вл - Ярославль. Добрыня + j , конечный гласный редуцируется, Н+j  + Добрынь.

Comment: Ну почему в + j = вл?! Я на всё согласная, только объясните!

Comment: Ну, тогда углубляйтесь в дебри исторической грамматики, в образование существительных и прилагательных древнерусского языка. Внимательно почитайте о трёх палатализациях по моей ссылке в вопросе о йотовой палатализации и увидите, что когда артикуляция наших предков поменялась,создались условия для палатализации, смягчения согласных в отдельных условиях, в частности все губные  + j давали вставку  -л- ,